# Joomla Contact Form Email

Tags: joomla

I'm new to Joomla and have been chucked in the deepend by a less than helpful colleague.  Currently enquiries submitted through the contact form set up on our website only go to him and I need to change this to get them myself, I've googled this and don't seem to be able to do what been suggested and I'm wondering if this is because he has only given me Administrator access and wanted to check the facts before I confront him.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is the contact form built in to the template? Does it use a third-party component?

Comment: Just change the email address in the contact form in the editor.  This is a separate field which will override any associated email for a given user.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Administrators can view and edit the core Contacts extension at `Components -> Contacts`.

The core Contacts extension is fairly basic and each contact can only have one email address (I just tested this in Joomla 3.5.1).

A better way to do this is probably to set up a generic "Enquiries" contact with an enquiries@yourdomainname.com email address and then forward enquiries@yourdomainname.com to as many email addresses as required.

Alternatively, search for a contact extension at http://extensions.joomla.org/category/contacts-and-feedback/contact-forms that will allow multiple recipient emails.

If the core Contacts extension is not being used, it's likely that contacts are already being handled by a third party extension. The most likely paces to look are under the Components menu or at `Extensions -> Modules`.

Comment: The emails currently go to enquiries@domainname.com so has this been set up outside of joomla? The enquiries form is an attachment so is there anyway to either change the address that it goes to so I can set up a new email address that I can direct to me or is easier to start again - colleague has now been sacked so he's not going to forward the current enquiries email to me!

Comment: Joomla doesn't do email by itself. You may need access to cPanel or similar to be able to reset the email account password or find where the form is set up in Joomla and change the email address there.

Comment: You can have a contact form go to any address you want, just change the address in the contact form.  This address is not displayed to the public unless you choose to do so.